# Adding link in php Wordpress footer

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need some help in php. I need an hyperlink on the phrase inetio s. r.o.

The code is following:

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_the_privacy_policy_link' ) ) {
    $footer_text = sprintf( _x( 'Copyright &copy; %1$s %2$s. Všechna práva vyhrazena. %3$s', '1: Year, 2: Site Title with home URL, 3: Privacy Policy Link', '' ), esc_attr( date_i18n( __( 'Y', '' ) ) ), '<a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">'. esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'inetio', 'display' ) ) . '</a>', get_the_privacy_policy_link() ) . ' &#124; ' . esc_html( $theme_data->get( 'inetio s. r. o.') ) . '&nbsp;' . esc_html__( 'vytvořilo inetio s. r. o.', 'solid-construction' ). '&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="'. esc_url( $theme_data->get( '' ) ) .'">'. esc_html( $theme_data->get( '' ) ) .'</a>';
}
```

Thanks for any help

boza

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it under WordPress built-in hook for this purpose.

```
add_action('wp_footer','dev_testing_func');
function dev_testing_func(){
    /*Place your Code here*/
}
```